# Pegar valor digitado pelo usuário no input com jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Olá! É o seguinte, no meu formulário, estou tentando obter o valor digitado pelo usuário no input da maneira abaixo:

```
// jQuery
function teste() {
var nome = $("#nome").val();
alert(nome); 
}

// HTML
<form method="post" action="#">
   <div class="field half first">
        <label for="nome">Nome</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome">
   </div>
   <div class="field half">
        <label for="sobrenome">Sobrenome</label>
        <input type="text" name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome">
   </div></form>
<button onClick="teste()">Teste</button>
```

Mas não retorna nenhum valor, gera um alert() em branco, independente do que o usuário tiver digitado. Alguém sabe o que pode ser? Caso seja útil, estou usando o Codeigniter

Comment: Isso pode acontecer caso você tenha mais de um elemento com o mesmo ID.

Comment: Verifiquei essa possibilidade, mas só há um elemento com o ID mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer assim que traz o valor do campo sem uso do **JQuery**:

```
function teste() {
   var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value
   alert(nome); 
}
```

Comment: Tentei, mas também retornou vazio. Parece que ele só retorna o valor do atributo value="" se for inserido, ai como não inseri, volta vazio

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery, no lugar desse onlick coloque uma Id `<button id="teste">Teste</button>`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="#">
   <div class="field half first">
        <label for="nome">Nome</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome">
   </div>
   <div class="field half">
        <label for="sobrenome">Sobrenome</label>
        <input type="text" name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome">
   </div></form>
<button id="teste">Teste</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#teste").click(function() {
    var nome = $("#nome").val();
    alert(nome); 
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Também não vai, parece que ele so consegue trazer o valor do atributo value="" e se ele não estiver, ai retorna vazio

Comment: se o valor estiver vazio vc precisa validar com um if($("#nome").val() == null) faca alguma coisa... mas o seu problema era o button que nao estava funcionando certo?